# linting error Value [{"endOfLine":"auto"},"singleQuote",true] should NOT have more than 2 items

Tags: eslint, lint, prettier

My configuration file has this:

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: 'eslint-config-universe',
  // do some additional things with it
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', { endOfLine: 'auto' }, 'singleQuote', true],
  },
};
```

When linting it throws an error:

```js
@my/modals:lint: ESLint: 8.31.0
@my/modals:lint: Error: package.json » @my/eslint-config:
@my/modals:lint:    Configuration for rule "prettier/prettier" is invalid:
@my/modals:lint:    Value [{"endOfLine":"auto"},"singleQuote",true] should NOT have more than 2 items.
```

What exactly does this mean?
I tried looking for info online. Someone suggested removing `eslint` globally, which I did. But it still gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

I counted, and you had three items. One map with a single key-value pair, one string, and one Boolean. That’s three. Someone wants to. I suspect you intended two key-value pairs.

Comment: Yes, I can count as well. The question is why it's giving an error and how to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why, but uninstalling pnpm local and installing globally with nvm and running lint again seemed to work.